# NoSuchMethodError for com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I'm using Apache beam with Cloud Dataflow Runner and getting the following exception when I try and run my pipeline:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubClient$TopicPath.getV1Beta1Path(PubsubClient.java:264)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner$StreamingPubsubIOReadTranslator.translate(DataflowRunner.java:856)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner$StreamingPubsubIOReadTranslator.translate(DataflowRunner.java:843)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.visitPrimitiveTransform(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:435)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:491)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:486)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:486)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$400(TransformHierarchy.java:235)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:210)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:409)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:381)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:171)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:523)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:153)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:295)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:281)
at com.souq.ApsalarEvent.<init>(ApsalarEvent.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2521)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1326)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:1273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:614)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.ensureInstance(ServletHolder.java:785)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1593)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've made sure I'm using the latest Guava version by adding this to my pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Decoding the method signature in the stack trace gives me:

```
void checkState(boolean, String, Object)
```

And I see this method in my project:[image]

Below is my complete POM

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>

<properties>
    <appengine.version>1.9.51</appengine.version>
    <appengine.maven.plugin.version>1.0.0</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
    <jetty-maven-plugin-version>9.3.7.v20160115</jetty-maven-plugin-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.3.9</maven>
</prerequisites>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version> <!-- required for Eclipse Mars -->
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-maven-plugin-version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Would it possible to try using guava 20 and providing your full pom file? I believe this is a known compatibility issue with guava 21.

Comment: I tried that and it still won't work. I added `<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>20.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>` to my POM but I still get the same error. What's weird is that I can see the method in my External Libraries. Not sure why it's throwing NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Also I've stripped down the project to just the Dataflow logic i.e. I removed the cloud pubsub dependency from my POM. All the servlet does know is initialize a dataflow pipeline. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Is there more to your pom file? I was wondering which dataflow version you were using as well. Is it possible to provide it in full?

Comment: @AlexAmato I'm using org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core version 2.0.0. I've updated the original question with my complete POM.

Comment: Adding a dependency to dependencyManagement only impacts direct dependencies that are declared in your pom.xml and any modules which declare this pom.xml as one of their parents. Since you don't have a multi-module build and you don't depend on guava the dependencyManagement section has no impact on your pom.xml

Comment: It seems as though you are trying to use AppEngine. Are you using AppEngine standard or AppEngine flex?

Comment: Also, if you are using any container environment like AppEngine or an IDE to test job creation, looking at your dependencies will only tell you what was included by your project and not what was included by the container environment. After creating the job, you should be able to get the list of files staged for Google Cloud Dataflow here https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.java#L200 and introspect the jars and classes using javap

Comment: @LukaszCwik I'm using app engine flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can find out what dependencies your project uses by using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`. Based upon your supplied `pom.xml`, your project is using `guava 20.0`.

In this case though, if you are using any container environment like AppEngine or an IDE to run/test job creation, looking at your Maven dependencies will only tell you what was included by your project and not what was included by the container environment. After creating the job, you should be able to get the list of files staged for Google Cloud Dataflow by invoking [`getFilesToStage()`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.0.0/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.java#L200):

```
Pipeline p = ...
...
p.run(options);
List<String> resources = options.as(DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.class).getFilesToStage();
System.out.println(resources);
```

You can download the jars from GCS and extract them. Afterwards introspect the classes using [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html). Doing this you will find another version of the offending `Preconditions` class. Removing the offending class is container specific but can be worked around by specifically setting the files to stage manually before running the pipeline.

Comment: I followed your instructions and saw that indeed 3 different versions of guava (19.0, 20.0, 21.0) are included in the final WAR file which I downloaded from Google Cloud Storage. Could you point me to some documentation that talks about how to remove specific (offending) libraries from Google App Engine? I can't seem to find anything online.

Comment: The easiest would be to copy the `detectClassPathResourcesToStage` code https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunner.java#L1181 and filter out any offending jars, calling `setFilesToStage` on the resulting list before running your job. I'm not aware of good resources that would address this problem beyond looking through similar `NoSuchMethodError` issues on AppEngine SO https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-app-engine%5D+NoSuchMethodError